# openCV 3.0 recoverPose wrong results

Tags: opencv

Does anyone can using openCV 3.0 recoverPose function with good results?
I've got:

```
cv::Mat r;
cv::Mat t;
cv::Mat E = cv::findEssentialMat(features1, features2);
cv::recoverPose(E, features1, features1, r, t);

float xAngle = radToDeg(atan2f(r.at<float>(2, 1), r.at<float>(2, 2)));
float yAngle = radToDeg(atan2f(-r.at<float>(2, 0), sqrtf(r.at<float>(2, 1) * r.at<float>(2, 1) + r.at<float>(2, 2) * r.at<float>(2, 2))));
float zAngle = radToDeg(atan2f(r.at<float>(1, 0), r.at<float>(0, 0)));
```

As input I use one image 1836x1836 dimensions and another image 1836x1836 which is just rotated 90 degrees to the left. I have rotated it using computer program so it is exactly rotate 90 degrees.

I expect result:

```
xAngle: 0

yAngle: 0

zAngle: 90 (or -90 depending on Z direction)
```

Unfortunately my results are:

```
xAngle: 90

yAngle: 0.113659

zAngle: 180
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: In recoverpose you are passing features1 instead of features2.

Answer (score 0):

The Essential matrix cannot be used to describe pure rotation. If you know that your images are related only by a rotation with no translation, then you have to estimate the homography (aka projective transformation) between them.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can get a pure rotation using openCV 3.0? I've read many documents and I am a little confused.

Comment: @Dima, care to elaborate?